# Error when generating Lyrics for our model

Tags: python, text-mining

*Hello! I am doing a group project with a friend and we're trying to generate rap lyrics, however,
when we ran the code we get this error and we don't know how to fix it. If you can help us that'd be amazing :). This is a draft of our code and we are currently trying to solve this issue. The Bars2 is a small txt file with just two songs since we want to debug the code. However, when we try to run the model we get the error that you can see. We've been trying to fix it for a few days but it is not working*

This is the code

```
with open('Bars2.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    dirty_rap_source = f.read()

rap_source = [x.split("\r")[0] for x in dirty_rap_source.split("\n")]
while "" in rap_source:
  rap_source.remove("")
while " " in rap_source:
  rap_source.remove(" ")
print("Your dataset's first 3 rap lines: ")
print(rap_source[:3])
!pip install markovify
!pip install pronouncing
# Imports
import markovify
import re
import pronouncing
import random
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
# These are just the parameters of the network.
depth = 4  # depth of the network. changing will require a retrain
maxsyllables = 16  # maximum syllables per line. Change this freely without retraining the network
rap_length = 5 # number of lines in the rap song
epochs_to_train = 10 # how many times the network trains on the whole dataset
def create_network(depth):
    # Sequential() creates a linear stack of layers
    model = Sequential()
    # Adds a LSTM layer as the first layer in the network with
    # 4 units (nodes), and a 2x2 tensor (which is the same shape as the
    # training data)
    model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(2, 2), return_sequences=True))
    # adds 'depth' number of layers to the network with 8 nodes each
    for i in range(depth):
        model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))
    # adds a final layer with 2 nodes for the output
    model.add(LSTM(2, return_sequences=True))
    # prints a summary representation of the model
    model.summary()
    # configures the learning process for the network / model
    # the optimizer function rmsprop: optimizes the gradient descent
    # the loss function: mse: will use the "mean_squared_error when trying to improve
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='mse')

    #if artist + ".rap" in os.listdir(".") and train_mode == False:
    #    # loads the weights from the hdf5 file saved earlier
    #    model.load_weights(str(artist + ".rap"))
    #    print "loading saved network: " + str(artist) + ".rap"
    return model


def markov(text_file):
    read = rap_source
    # markovify goes line by line of the lyrics.txt file and
    # creates a model of the text which allows us to use
    # make_sentence() later on to create a bar for lyrics
    # creates a probability distribution for all the words
    # so it can generate words based on the current word we're on
    text_model = markovify.NewlineText(read)
    return text_model


# used when generating bars and making sure the length is not longer
# than the max syllables, and will continue to generate bars until
# the amount of syllables is less than the max syllables
def syllables(line):
    count = 0
    for word in line.split(" "):
        vowels = 'aeiouy'
        word = word.lower().strip(".:;?!")
        #if not word:
          #continue
        if word[0] in vowels:
            count += 1
        for index in range(1, len(word)):
            if word[index] in vowels and word[index - 1] not in vowels:
                count += 1
        if word.endswith('e'):
            count -= 1
        if word.endswith('le'):
            count += 1
        if count == 0:
            count += 1
    return count / maxsyllables


# writes a rhyme list to a rhymes file that allows for use when
# building the dataset, and composing the rap
'''def rhymeindex(lyrics):
    #if str(artist) + ".rhymes" in os.listdir(".") and train_mode == False:
    #    print "loading saved rhymes from " + str(artist) + ".rhymes"
    #    return open(str(artist) + ".rhymes", "r").read().split("\n")
    if True:
        rhyme_master_list = []
        print("Alright, building the list of all the rhymes")
        for i in lyrics:
            # grabs the last word in each bar
            word = re.sub(r"\W+", '', i.split(" ")[-1]).lower()
            #print(f'Printing word: {word}')
            # pronouncing.rhymes gives us a word that rhymes with the word being passed in
            rhymeslist = pronouncing.rhymes(word)
            # need to convert the unicode rhyme words to UTF8
            rhymeslist = [x.encode('UTF8') for x in rhymeslist]
            # rhymeslistends contains the last two characters for each word
            # that could potentially rhyme with our word
            rhymeslistends = []
            for i in rhymeslist:
                rhymeslistends.append(i[-2:])
            try:
                # rhymescheme gets all the unique two letter endings and then
                # finds the one that occurs the most
                rhymescheme = max(set(rhymeslistends), key=rhymeslistends.count)
            except Exception:
                rhymescheme = word[-2:]
            rhyme_master_list.append(rhymescheme)
        # rhyme_master_list is a list of the two letters endings that appear
        # the most in the rhyme list for the word
        rhyme_master_list = list(set(rhyme_master_list))

        reverselist = [x[::-1] for x in rhyme_master_list]
        reverselist = sorted(str(reverselist))
        print(f'Sorted reverselist: {reverselist}')
        # rhymelist is a list of the two letter endings (reversed)
        # the reason the letters are reversed and sorted is so
        # if the network messes up a little bit and doesn't return quite
        # the right values, it can often lead to picking the rhyme ending next to the
        # expected one in the list. But now the endings will be sorted and close together
        # so if the network messes up, that's alright and as long as it's just close to the
        # correct rhymes
        rhymelist = [x[::-1] for x in reverselist]

        #f = open(str(artist) + ".rhymes", "w")
        #f.write("\n".join(rhymelist))
        #f.close()
        print(rhymelist)
        return rhymelist'''

def rhymeindex(lyrics):
    if str('bobo') + ".rhymes" in os.listdir("."):
        print ("loading saved rhymes from " + str('bobo') + ".rhymes")
        return open(str('bobo') + ".rhymes", "r",encoding='utf-8').read().split("\n")
    else:
        rhyme_master_list = []
        print ("Building list of rhymes:")
        for i in lyrics:
            word = re.sub(r"\W+", '', i.split(" ")[-1]).lower()
            rhymeslist = pronouncing.rhymes(word)
            rhymeslistends = []      
            for i in rhymeslist:
                rhymeslistends.append(i[-2:])
            try:
                rhymescheme = max(set(rhymeslistends), key=rhymeslistends.count)
            except Exception:
                rhymescheme = word[-2:]
            rhyme_master_list.append(rhymescheme)
        rhyme_master_list = list(set(rhyme_master_list))
        reverselist = [x[::-1] for x in rhyme_master_list]
        reverselist = sorted(reverselist)
        rhymelist = [x[::-1] for x in reverselist]
        print("List of Sorted 2-Letter Rhyme Ends:")
        print(rhymelist)
        f = open(str('bobo') + ".rhymes", "w", encoding='utf-8')
        f.write("\n".join(rhymelist))
        f.close()
        return rhymelist


# converts the index of the most common rhyme ending
# into a float
def rhyme(line, rhyme_list):
    word = re.sub(r"\W+", '', line.split(" ")[-1]).lower()
    rhymeslist = pronouncing.rhymes(word)
    rhymeslist = [x.encode('UTF8') for x in rhymeslist]
    rhymeslistends = []
    for i in rhymeslist:
        rhymeslistends.append(i[-2:])
    try:
        rhymescheme = max(set(rhymeslistends), key=rhymeslistends.count)
    except Exception:
        rhymescheme = word[-2:]
    try:
        float_rhyme = rhyme_list.index(rhymescheme)
        float_rhyme = float_rhyme / float(len(rhyme_list))
        return float_rhyme
    except Exception:
        return None


# grabs each line of the lyrics file and puts them
# in their own index of a list, and then removes any empty lines
# from the lyrics file and returns the list as bars
def split_lyrics_file(text):
    #text = open(text_file).read()
    #text = text.split("\n")
    while "" in text:
        text.remove("")
    return text


# only ran when not training
def generate_lyrics(lyrics_file):
    bars = []
    last_words = []
    lyriclength = len(lyrics_file)
    count = 0
    markov_model = markov((". ").join(lyrics_file) + ".")

    while len(bars) < lyriclength / 9 and count < lyriclength * 2:
        # By default, the make_sentence method tries, a maximum of 10 times per invocation,
        # to make a sentence that doesn't overlap too much with the original text.
        # If it is successful, the method returns the sentence as a string.
        # If not, it returns None. (https://github.com/jsvine/markovify)
        bar = markov_model.make_sentence()

        # make sure the bar isn't 'None' and that the amount of
        # syllables is under the max syllables
        if type(bar) != type(None) and syllables(bar) < 1:

            # function to get the last word of the bar
            def get_last_word(bar):
                last_word = bar.split(" ")[-1]
                # if the last word is punctuation, get the word before it
                if last_word[-1] in "!.?,":
                    last_word = last_word[:-1]
                return last_word

            last_word = get_last_word(bar)
            # only use the bar if it is unique and the last_word
            # has only been seen less than 3 times
            if bar not in bars and last_words.count(last_word) < 3:
                bars.append(bar)
                last_words.append(last_word)
                count += 1

    return bars


# used to construct the 2x2 inputs for the LSTMs
# the lyrics being passed in are lyrics (original lyrics if being trained,
# or ours if it's already trained)
def build_dataset(lyrics, rhyme_list):
    dataset = []
    line_list = []
    # line_list becomes a list of the line from the lyrics, the syllables for that line (either 0 or 1 since
    # syllables uses integer division by maxsyllables (16)), and then rhyme returns the most common word
    # endings of the words that could rhyme with the last word of line
    for line in lyrics:
        line_list = [line, syllables(line), rhyme(line, rhyme_list)]
        dataset.append(line_list)

    x_data = []
    y_data = []

    # using range(len(dataset)) - 3 because of the way the indices are accessed to
    # get the lines
    for i in range(len(dataset) - 3):
        line1 = dataset[i][1:]
        line2 = dataset[i + 1][1:]
        line3 = dataset[i + 2][1:]
        line4 = dataset[i + 3][1:]

        # populate the training data
        # grabs the syllables and rhyme index here
        x = [line1[0], line1[1], line2[0], line2[1]]
        x = np.array(x)
        # the data is shaped as a 2x2 array where each row is a
        # [syllable, rhyme_index] pair
        x = x.reshape(2, 2)
        

        # populate the target data
        y = [line3[0], line3[1], line4[0], line4[1]]
        y = np.array(y)
        y = y.reshape(2, 2)

        if type(x) is np.ndarray and type(y) is np.ndarray:
          x_data.append(x)
          y_data.append(y)
        else:
          continue

    # returns the 2x2 arrays as datasets
    x_data = np.array(x_data)
    y_data = np.array(y_data)

    # print "x shape " + str(x_data.shape)
    # print "y shape " + str(y_data.shape)
    return x_data, y_data

# only used when not training
def compose_rap(lines, rhyme_list, lyrics_file, model):
    rap_vectors = []
    human_lyrics = split_lyrics_file(lyrics_file)

    # choose a random line to start in from given lyrics
    initial_index = random.choice(range(len(human_lyrics) - 1))
    # create an initial_lines list consisting of 2 lines
    initial_lines = human_lyrics[initial_index:initial_index + 8]

    starting_input = []
    for line in initial_lines:
        # appends a [syllable, rhyme_index] pair to starting_input
        starting_input.append([syllables(line), rhyme(line, rhyme_list)])
        print(f'Printing starting_input: {starting_input}')

    # predict generates output predictions for the given samples
    # it's reshaped as a (1, 2, 2) so that the model can predict each
    # 2x2 matrix of [syllable, rhyme_index] pairs
    starting_vectors = model.predict(np.array([starting_input]).flatten().reshape(4, 2, 2).astype('float32'))
    rap_vectors.append(starting_vectors)
    print(f'Printing starting_vectors: {starting_vectors}')

    for i in range(rap_length):
        rap_vectors.append(model.predict(np.array([rap_vectors[-1]]).flatten().reshape(4, 2, 2)))
        print(f'Printing rap_vectors: {rap_vectors}')

    return rap_vectors


def vectors_into_song(vectors, generated_lyrics, rhyme_list):
    print("\n\n")
    print("About to write rap (this could take a moment)...")
    print("\n\n")

    # compare the last words to see if they are the same, if they are
    # increment a penalty variable which grants penalty points for being
    # uncreative
    def last_word_compare(rap, line2):
        penalty = 0
        for line1 in rap:
            word1 = line1.split(" ")[-1]
            word2 = line2.split(" ")[-1]

            # remove any punctuation from the words
            #while word1[-1] in "?!,.":
                #word1 = word1[:-1]

            #while word2[-1] in "?!,.":
                #word2 = word2[:-1]

            if word1 == word2:
                penalty += 0.2

        return penalty

    # vector_half is a single [syllable, rhyme_index] pair
    # returns a score rating for a given line
    def calculate_score(vector_half, syllables, rhyme, penalty):
        print(f'vector_half: {vector_half}, syllables: {syllables}, rhyme: {rhyme}, penalty: {penalty}')
        desired_syllables = vector_half[0]
        desired_rhyme = vector_half[1]
        # desired_syllables is the number of syllables we want
        desired_syllables = desired_syllables * maxsyllables
        # desired rhyme is the index of the rhyme we want
        desired_rhyme = desired_rhyme * len(rhyme_list)

        # generate a score by subtracting from 1 the sum of the difference between
        # predicted syllables and generated syllables and the difference between
        # the predicted rhyme and generated rhyme and then subtract the penalty
        score = 1.0 - (abs((float(desired_syllables) - float(syllables))) + abs(
            (float(desired_rhyme) - float(rhyme)))) - penalty

        return score

    # generated a list of all the lines from generated_lyrics with their
    # line, syllables, and rhyme float value
    dataset = []
    for line in generated_lyrics:
        line_list = [line, syllables(line), rhyme(line, rhyme_list)]
        dataset.append(line_list)

    rap = []

    vector_halves = []
    for vector in vectors:
        # vectors are the 2x2 rap_vectors (predicted bars) generated by compose_rap()
        # separate every vector into a half (essentially one bar) where each
        # has a pair of [syllables, rhyme_index]
        vector_halves.append(list(vector[0][0]))
        vector_halves.append(list(vector[0][1]))

    for vector in vector_halves:
        # Each vector (predicted bars) is scored against every generated bar ('item' below)
        # to find the generated bar that best matches (highest score) the vector predicted
        # by the model. This bar is then added to the final rap and also removed from the
        # generated lyrics (dataset) so that we don't get duplicate lines in the final rap.
        scorelist = []
        for item in dataset:
            # item is one of the generated bars from the Markov model
            line = item[0]

            if len(rap) != 0:
                penalty = last_word_compare(rap, line)
            else:
                penalty = 0
            # calculate the score of the current line
            total_score = calculate_score(vector, item[1], item[2], penalty)
            score_entry = [line, total_score]
            # add the score of the current line to a scorelist
            scorelist.append(score_entry)

        fixed_score_list = []
        for score in scorelist:
            fixed_score_list.append(float(score[1]))
        # get the line with the max valued score from the fixed_score_list
        max_score = max(fixed_score_list)
        for item in scorelist:
            if item[1] == max_score:
                # append item[0] (the line) to the rap
                rap.append(item[0])
                print(str(item[0]))

                # remove the line we added to the rap so
                # it doesn't get chosen again
                for i in dataset:
                    if item[0] == i[0]:
                        dataset.remove(i)
                        break
                break
    return rap


def train(x_data, y_data, model):
    # fit is used to train the model for 5 'epochs' (iterations) where
    # the x_data is the training data, and the y_data is the target data
    # x is the training and y is the target data
    # batch_size is a subset of the training data (2 in this case)
    # verbose simply shows a progress bar
    model.fit(np.array(x_data), np.array(y_data),
              batch_size=4,
              epochs=epochs_to_train,
              verbose=1)
    # save_weights saves the best weights from training to a hdf5 file
    #model.save_weights(artist + ".rap")


def main(depth):
    train_mode = True
    model = create_network(depth)
    # change the lyrics file to the file with the lyrics you want to be trained on
    
    text_file = rap_source
    
    bars = split_lyrics_file(text_file)



    rhyme_list = rhymeindex(bars)
    
    print(f'rhyme_list: {rhyme_list}')
    x_data, y_data = build_dataset(bars, rhyme_list)
    x_data = np.asarray(x_data).astype('float32')
    y_data = np.asarray(y_data).astype('float32')
    train(x_data, y_data, model)
    
    bars = generate_lyrics(text_file)
    vectors = compose_rap(bars, rhyme_list, text_file, model)
    print(f'Printing vectors: {vectors}')
    rap = vectors_into_song(vectors, bars, rhyme_list)
    
    for bar in rap:
        print(bar)
```

This is the error

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 2, 4)              112       
                                                                 
 lstm_1 (LSTM)               (None, 2, 8)              416       
                                                                 
 lstm_2 (LSTM)               (None, 2, 8)              544       
                                                                 
 lstm_3 (LSTM)               (None, 2, 8)              544       
                                                                 
 lstm_4 (LSTM)               (None, 2, 8)              544       
                                                                 
 lstm_5 (LSTM)               (None, 2, 2)              88        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 2,248
Trainable params: 2,248
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Building list of rhymes:
List of Sorted 2-Letter Rhyme Ends:
['m3', 'ca', 'ia', 'la', 'pa', 'ra', 'ta', 'ib', 'ob', 'ed', 'nd', 'rd', 'ud', 'ce', 'de', 'ee', 'ge', 'ke', 'le', 'me', 'ne', 're', 'se', 'te', 'ze', 'lf', 'ag', 'ng', 'og', 'ah', 'ch', 'gh', 'oh', 'sh', 'th', 'uh', 'ai', 'li', 'ni', 'si', 'zi', 'ck', 'rk', 'al', 'el', 'll', 'rl', 'am', 'im', 'um', 'an', 'en', 'in', 'on', 'un', 'wn', 'ao', 'co', 'jo', 'ko', 'mo', 'so', 'ap', 'ip', 'pp', 'ar', 'er', 'ur', "'s", '0s', 'as', 'cs', 'ds', 'es', 'gs', 'ks', 'ls', 'ms', 'ns', 'ps', 'rs', 'ss', 'ts', 'us', "'t", 'at', 'ct', 'et', 'it', 'nt', 'rt', 'tt', 'ut', 'au', 'ew', 'ow', 'ay', 'by', 'ly', 'ny', 'py', 'ty', 'iz', 'tz']
rhyme_list: ['m3', 'ca', 'ia', 'la', 'pa', 'ra', 'ta', 'ib', 'ob', 'ed', 'nd', 'rd', 'ud', 'ce', 'de', 'ee', 'ge', 'ke', 'le', 'me', 'ne', 're', 'se', 'te', 'ze', 'lf', 'ag', 'ng', 'og', 'ah', 'ch', 'gh', 'oh', 'sh', 'th', 'uh', 'ai', 'li', 'ni', 'si', 'zi', 'ck', 'rk', 'al', 'el', 'll', 'rl', 'am', 'im', 'um', 'an', 'en', 'in', 'on', 'un', 'wn', 'ao', 'co', 'jo', 'ko', 'mo', 'so', 'ap', 'ip', 'pp', 'ar', 'er', 'ur', "'s", '0s', 'as', 'cs', 'ds', 'es', 'gs', 'ks', 'ls', 'ms', 'ns', 'ps', 'rs', 'ss', 'ts', 'us', "'t", 'at', 'ct', 'et', 'it', 'nt', 'rt', 'tt', 'ut', 'au', 'ew', 'ow', 'ay', 'by', 'ly', 'ny', 'py', 'ty', 'iz', 'tz']
Epoch 1/10
96/96 [==============================] - 14s 11ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/10
96/96 [==============================] - 1s 12ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/10
96/96 [==============================] - 1s 10ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 4/10
96/96 [==============================] - 1s 11ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 5/10
96/96 [==============================] - 1s 12ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 6/10
96/96 [==============================] - 1s 12ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 7/10
96/96 [==============================] - 1s 11ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 8/10
96/96 [==============================] - 1s 10ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 9/10
96/96 [==============================] - 1s 11ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 10/10
96/96 [==============================] - 1s 11ms/step - loss: nan
Printing starting_input: [[0.4375, None]]
Printing starting_input: [[0.4375, None], [0.4375, None]]
Printing starting_input: [[0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.4375, None]]
Printing starting_input: [[0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.625, None]]
Printing starting_input: [[0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.625, None], [0.625, None]]
Printing starting_input: [[0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.625, None], [0.625, None], [0.9375, None]]
Printing starting_input: [[0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.625, None], [0.625, None], [0.9375, None], [0.625, None]]
Printing starting_input: [[0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.4375, None], [0.625, None], [0.625, None], [0.9375, None], [0.625, None], [0.625, None]]
Printing starting_vectors: [[[nan nan]
  [nan nan]]

 [[nan nan]
  [nan nan]]

 [[nan nan]
  [nan nan]]

 [[nan nan]
  [nan nan]]]
Printing rap_vectors: [array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32)]
Printing rap_vectors: [array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32)]
Printing rap_vectors: [array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32)]
Printing rap_vectors: [array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32)]
Printing rap_vectors: [array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32)]
Printing vectors: [array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32), array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]]], dtype=float32)]



About to write rap (this could take a moment)...



vector_half: [nan, nan], syllables: 0.6875, rhyme: None, penalty: 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e316dd91dea0> in <module>
----> 1 main(depth) # run this to get the actual rap

<ipython-input-12-2899ad922142> in main(depth)
    433     vectors = compose_rap(bars, rhyme_list, text_file, model)
    434     print(f'Printing vectors: {vectors}')
--> 435     rap = vectors_into_song(vectors, bars, rhyme_list)
    436 
    437     for bar in rap:

<ipython-input-12-2899ad922142> in vectors_into_song(vectors, generated_lyrics, rhyme_list)
    371                 penalty = 0
    372             # calculate the score of the current line
--> 373             total_score = calculate_score(vector, item[1], item[2], penalty)
    374             score_entry = [line, total_score]
    375             # add the score of the current line to a scorelist

<ipython-input-12-2899ad922142> in calculate_score(vector_half, syllables, rhyme, penalty)
    335         # the predicted rhyme and generated rhyme and then subtract the penalty
    336         score = 1.0 - (abs((float(desired_syllables) - float(syllables))) + abs(
--> 337             (float(desired_rhyme) - float(rhyme)))) - penalty
    338 
    339         return score

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```